# Adding Serilog Enrichers using App Config

Tags: c#, json, serilog

For Serilog logs enrichment using an App config how can i add standard enrichers like ProcessId, ThreadId, MachineName? The syntax to add property enricher is below but am trying to use the above standard enrichers. There's an option to implement [application json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486481/is-there-a-way-to-enrich-the-log-with-a-property-from-configuration) which i want to avoid as it needs Serilog 2.6. Any ideas how this can be done?

```
<add key="serilog:enrich:with-property:Version" value="1.0" />
```

Comment: Also using LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.KeyValuePairs(...) how i can pass enrichers?

Answer (score 5):

Add the standard enricher with the below syntax, you also need to refer the dll for the enricher, see below for ThreadId enricher.

```
    <add key="serilog:using:Thread" value="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" />
    <add key="serilog:enrich:WithThreadId" />
```